# Record video with web cam and get first frame of that and compare it with next frames in matlab

Tags: matlab

how can i record video by webcam in matlab and take frame of that and compare it with next frames

this is my code:

```
camvid1 = videoinput('winvideo',1,'YUY2_640x480');
subplot(211)
h1 = image; 
axis ij 
preview(camvid1,h1) 
start(camvid1);
pause(2),camfrm1=getdata(camvid1);
camfrm1=rgb2gray(imread(camfrm1));
for i=1:n
camfrm2=getdata(camvid1);
camfrm2=rgb2gray(camfrm2);
bt=abs(double(camfrm2)-bouble(camfrm1));
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly isn't working?

Comment: i cant get frames of video and read it

Comment: i cant get frame of video and compare it with next frames

Comment: ??? Error using ==> strfind
Input strings must have one row.

Error in ==> imread at 340
if (strfind(filename, '://'))

Error in ==> GUITest>btn1_Callback at 90
camfrm1=rgb2gray(imread(camfrm1));

Answer (score 0):

[imread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) is used to read a file from a folder which is already in a particular compressed or uncompressed format. In your case, you have raw data, on which you can perform operations. So, try using:

```
 camfrm1 = rgb2gray(camfrm1);
```

This should work.
There is a second typo:

```
 bt = abs(double(camfrm2)-double(camfrm1));
```

Comment: 1.sorry about bouble!! 2.camfrm1=rgb2gray(camfrm1); dosn't work.

Comment: Can you tell what the error is now? I am assuming you are getting different error.

Comment: Error in ==> rgb2gray at 35
X = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in ==> GUITest>btn1_Callback at 90
camfrm1=rgb2gray(camfrm1);

Comment: Interesting, it should be throwing an error, because parse_inputs checks for the type of the input. Could you paste the following output by adding this line just before the rgb2gray call: whos camfrm1